# Displaying ICollection in a datagridcolumn cell

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a Column Called "Tags" And it consist of attributes of a person. For example a person called BoB and have tags such ass [Funny, Nice, Outgoing]. I am able to filter the Datagrid searching for tags. I can only display the First one only. My problem is that I want to be able to show more than one tag at a time.

[TagDataGrid](http://i.snag.gy/saOz0.jpg)      [TagAttributes](http://i.snag.gy/ETLsc.jpg)

Person.cs

```
public class Person
{...
    public virtual ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; } 
...}
```

Tags.cs

```
public class Tags
{....
    public string Tag { get; set; } 
....}
```

PersonDTO.cs

```
public class PersonDTO : IDTO
{....
    public string Tag { get; set; } 
....}
```

ViewModel:

```
using (var ctx = DB.Get()) 
{
    Items.AddRange(ctx.People.Select(x => new PersonDTO
    {.... 
        Tags = x.Tags.FirstOrDefault().Tag
    ....}
}
```

Datatemplate Trial:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tags.Tag}"></TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and create a template for displaying the list, or alternatively implement [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to programmatically convert the list to a single string (using [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example).

Update: in order to display a collection, you need an `ItemsControl` - for example, `ListBox`. Something like this:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Using `IValueConverter`:

```
public class JoinArrayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var col = value as ICollection<Tags>;
        if(col==null)
          throw new InvalidArgumentException("Expected a ICollection<Tags>");
        return string.Join(", ",col.ToArray());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // No one ever implement this one :)
    }
}
```

A value converter convert your original value (a collection) into a new one (a string). This way you can use a regular text column. Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the rest of the information you need in order to use this class.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the DataGridTemplateColumn, Nothing is pulling through. Updated my code :s

Comment: Updated. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to display it in a fancy list or as a simple string (like "Funny,Nice")?

Comment: Then use a value converter similar to the one in my answer.

Comment: Hey @opd I almost got it working, I made and implemented everything only issue now is the return line. this is the error i got http://snag.gy/Gv2bT.jpg

Comment: Nevermind, instead of a string.join method, I did a foreach value in col and concatenated the values! thanks for showing me IValueConverter!

Comment: Glad to help! But don't use a foreach - try this: `return string.Join(", ",col.Select(t=>t.ToString()).ToArray());`. Good luck!